# iOS Crash Pushing Mail Compose View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have been having issues of late.  This used to work just fine, but recently, maybe as far back as iOS 10.0, this will just cause the app to crash, with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

What needs to be changed?

```
-(void) emailIt {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"To Fritch Church of Christ"];


    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tbrass84@yahoo.com"];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Sent from the Fritch Church of Christ iOS App";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];

}
```

Comment: Are you really not using ARC? And please update your question with the exact and complete error message and point out the exact line causing the issue.

Comment: Why are you not checking if email is supported before trying to create the mail composer?

Comment: @rmaddy `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`.  The line that crashes is `[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];`